# Value selected from dropdown is null in model page

Tags: .net, forms, asp.net-core

I am trying to make a form in Razor Pages .NetCore where the next things happen:

- The user selects a date from the datepicker
- Based on that date some values will populate a dropdown
- The user selects a value from the dropdown and that value goes in the database

The problem is that when submitting the form, the value selected from the dropdown is null (though in the UI the dropdown values appear and can be selected)

In html

```
@section Scripts {
<script>
    $("#SelectDate").on("change", function () {
            var myDate = $(this).val();

            $("#select").empty();
            $("#select").append("<option value=''>select </option>");
            $.getJSON(`?handler=Date&date=${myDate}`, (data) => {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    $("#select").append("<option value='"  + "'>" + item.value + "</option>");
                });
            });
        });
</script>
}

<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
       <label asp-for="SelectDate" class="control-label"></label>
       <input asp-for="SelectDate" class="form-control" />
       <span asp-validation-for="SelectDate" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>

<select id="select" asp-for="SelectedValue"></select>

<div class="form-group button-position col-md4">
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

In my model

```
[BindProperty]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime SelectDate { get; set; }

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string SelectedValue { get;set; }

public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    //here SelectedValue is null
    Debug.WriteLine(SelectedValue)    
           
    return Redirect(Url.Page(indexPage));
}


//method that puts the values on the dropdown 
public IActionResult OnGetDate(DateTime date)
{
    //Here I set the values that are going to the dropdown (these are string values)

      foreach (var h in myValues)
      {
             model.Add(new Values
             {
                  Value = h
              });
      }

      return new JsonResult(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your code like

```
$("#select").append(""<option value='" + item.value + "'>"  + "'>" + item.value + "</option>");
```